# socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() weird issue

Tags: java, windows, sockets

I have a legacy server application written in java which has been running fine over the last six years on a windows 2003 machine running Java 6.
We recently migrated the application to a brand new windows 2008 machine running the latest version of java.
Although the application seems to work fine, there is one weird issue

The code `String remoteip=socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()` seems to return the internet IP of the server machine instead of returning the IP of the remote client.
This was working properly on both Linux and Windows 2003 machines over the last 6-7 years.

To double check all settings, I set up a small php website on IIS and printed the value of REMOTE_ADDr variable. It printed the correct IP address of the client.

Any clues on what could be confusing the java app?

Answer (score 3):

The Java doc says this:

```
 getInetAddress()
 Returns the local address of this server socket.
```

Probably previously you were running the server and the client on the same machine.

To be more specific: You probably have a ServerSocket(sSocket) waiting for connections from clients.
If you call sSocket.getInetAddress(), you will get the IP address of the server.
On the other hand, the role of a ServerSocket is to bind to a IP address and port and to wait for connections from clients. When such a connection is made, the sSocket.accept() method returns a Socket which represents the connection of the server to that specific client (cSocket). Calling cSocket.getRemoteAddress() returns the IP of the client

Comment: Exactly. The operation of this API has no ever changed.

Comment: In the call socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() , socket is the cSocket received after the accept.This has worked for over 8 years Is this a change in the new version of Java?Should i change this to socket.getRemoteAddress()

Comment: as per java docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress() getInetAddress
public InetAddress getInetAddress()Returns the address to which the socket is connected. 

Returns:
the remote IP address to which this socket is connected, or null if the socket is not connected.

Comment: tried using cSocket.getRemoteAddress().toString(), now isntead of returning the server ip it returns /serverip:port. It is still returning server IP

Comment: The client is running on another machine ? is cSocket connected, can you send/receive messages on it ?

Comment: This is a production application.There are multiple clients and all are able to connect.the only issue is the strange behaviour of the getInetAddress and getRemoteSocketAddress functions